# How can we solve this system of linear inequalities?

Tags: optimization, problem-solving

Let $c_i$ be a given non-negative integer for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. I would like to find the non-negative integers $a_i$ and $b_i$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that:

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
c_i = a_i+b_i, & \text{ for all } i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\\
a_i < a_{i+1}, & \text{ for all } i\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}\\
b_i > b_{i+1}, & \text{ for all } i\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}\\
b_i\ge 0 \text{ and integer }, & \text{ for all } i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\\
a_i\ge 0 \text{ and integer }, & \text{ for all } i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

How to solve this system? Is there a single solution?

Answer (score 0):

What if $c_i=0$ $\forall i$?  Then for the first condition you'd need $a_i=b_i=0$ $\forall i$.  But then the 2nd and 3rd conditions cannot be satisfied.

Comment: Isn't he asking for a solution?

Comment: @GuachoPerez Showing there can be no general solution, via a counter-example, is a solution.

Comment: But he asked how to solve.

Comment: @GuachoPerez The answer is you cannot solve it.  For example if I ask you how to solve $x^3+y^3=z^3$ in non-zero integers, the correct answer is "there is no solution".

Comment: But you are not proving it, what you are saying is equivalent to saying that because $(0,0)$ is not a solution to $x+y=1$, there is no solution .

Comment: @GuachoPerez The way to prove a statement is not true is via a counter-example, and that's what I've done.  So yes, that's a proof.

Comment: Say $c_1 = 5$ and $c_2 = 3$, then $a_1 = 2, b_1= 3$ and $a_2 = 2, b_2 = 1$, that is a solution. Maybe not a general solution, but he was not asking if there was a general solution.

Comment: @GuachoPerez What you're failing to grasp is that $c_1$ and $c_2$ are *given* so to properly answer the question you need a general solution that works for any $c_1$ and $c_2$.  By providing a counter-example one shows no such general solution exists.  That, therefore, is a complete answer.  Giving an example where a solution does exist is immaterial.  If he had said "give an example" then you'd be right.  But he asked for a general solution.

Comment: Taking your previous example $x^3+y^3=z^3$, wouldn't your answer amount to saying "let $x=1$ and $y=1$ therefore there is no solution?" I agree that there may be no general solution, but giving a counter example does not prove it, or does it? Because there are methods that give Pythagorean Triples, the fact that a single example does not work does not mean that FLT is also true for $n=2$

Comment: @GuachoPerez No, that's not what my answer would amount to.  But admittedly it wasn't the best analogy.  Try this one instead.  What if I said I need to show that for all integers $x$ and $y$ there exists an integer $z$ such that $x=y+z^2$.  The correct answer is that the statement is false since for $x=3$ and $y=1$ there is no such $z$ since $\sqrt{2}$ is not an integer.  What would not be an appropriate answer would be to say if $x=5$ and $y=1$ then $z=2$.

Comment: Oh, alright, I thought the question was asking for a method to solve the problem, not a proof that for every possible value of $c$ there'd be a solution. Because there might be values of $c$ for which the method would work, and others for which it would return some contradiction, e.g. $c_i=0 \forall i$

Comment: @GuachoPerez Right, what you have shown is that sometimes there are solutions.  But the OP would have to be more specific on what $c_1$ and $c_2$ are in order to find a solution because there does not exist one in general.